# How to swipe images

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a simple gallery of images in which I have an image to be displayed at a time on the device screen. When we swipe the screen from left to right it should show the next image.
For that I implemented a view flipper and added image views to it.
But I don't know how to catch that swipe event.
Can anyone tell me with an example?

Comment: And why would you want to catch that swipe event?

Comment: i want to catch that swipe event so that based on the swipe i can change the images from left to right or vice versa

Answer (score 17):

I needed the same thing for my app, and used a `ViewPager`:
http://blog.sqisland.com/2012/09/android-swipe-image-viewer-with-viewpager.html

Previously I used a `ImageSwitcher` combined with a `GestureDetector`: http://blog.sqisland.com/2012/07/android-swipe-image-viewer.html

The code with `ViewPager` is much simpler, and the experience is much better because the image slides as your finger swipe across the screen. I create `ImageView` directly, no fragments required.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! You just made my day with your [solution](https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer) and saved me hours of labor. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 5):

**You can create a custom Pager Adapter for your ViewPager:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.cap8, R.drawable.cap2, R.drawable.cap3, R.drawable.cap1, R.drawable.cap5,
            R.drawable.cap6, R.drawable.cap7, R.drawable.cap9, R.drawable.cap4,
            R.drawable.cap10

    };

    ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        container.addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Use the ViewPager in your layout and register the adapter:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mvieww"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this way also, without using view flipper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

<ImageView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:layout_margin="10dip"
                 android:id="@+id/image_place_holder"
                 />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

 private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3 };

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity ";
ImageView imageView;
float startXValue = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_place_holder);
    imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[num]);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {    
    float endXValue = 0;
    float x1 = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    switch (action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            startXValue = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);

            return true;

        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            endXValue = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
            if (endXValue > startXValue) {
                if (endXValue - startXValue > 100) {
                System.out.println("Left-Right");
                imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[2]);
                }
            }else {
                if (startXValue -endXValue> 100) {
                System.out.println("Right-Left");
                imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[0]);

                     }
                         }
        return true;


           default:
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `ViewPager` available in the [Android Support Jar](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). Here is a tutorial: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

You dont want use `Gallery` as some suggest as its not deprecated. However from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) they suggest the `ViewPager` and `HorizantleScrollView` to solve this problem relatively easily:

```
This class is deprecated.
    This widget is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include
    HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.
```

Comment: IMO ViewPager is not appropriate in all cases. It's associated generally with fragments, and if you only want to swipe images using a separate fragment with each swipe seems overkill

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that,It surly works without any view

```
public class Swipe extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
//private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
ImageView img;


View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1swipe);

    img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
            //Log.i("Hello my Log 1","How dfgfd are you");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and declare this method in your .java

```
private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            Log.i("Hello my Log 2","How dfgfd are you");
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Log.i("dfsd", "Right to left");
                return false; // Right to left
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Left to right
            }

            if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Bottom to top
            } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Top to bottom
            }

            return false;
        }'
```

May be [this](http://android-journey.blogspot.in/2010/01/android-gestures.html) will help you for arranging all the swiping of Images

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i achieved:

```
package com.demoimageslider;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(
                super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    }

    public static class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout,
                    container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout,
                    container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag3_layout,
                    container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }

    public static class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements
            ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
        private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                // view.setAlpha(0);
                ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as
                // well
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
                float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                if (position < 0) {
                    // view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
                    ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, horzMargin - vertMargin
                            / 2);
                } else {
                    // view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
                    ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, -horzMargin + vertMargin
                            / 2);
                }

                // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                // view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                // view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
                ViewHelper.setScaleX(view, scaleFactor);
                ViewHelper.setScaleY(view, scaleFactor);

                // Fade the page relative to its size.
                // view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
                // (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                // (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

                ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, MIN_ALPHA + (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE)
                        / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                // view.setAlpha(0);
                ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used nineoldroids library to support effects on older android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement it using gallery widget?

[Here is the gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html).

Comment: Gallery is deprecated :( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html