# Swipe with Image list view in on item click listener

Tags: android, swipe

I am working with Android app to swipe an image from list view. But I don't know the answer. I got values in list view and where clicking an image with item click listener it shown in another intent, I want without going back, show image from top to bottom in list view using swipe method.

Comment: Have a look here, https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swipe images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101629/how-to-swipe-images)

Comment: Here is full solution for such requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426980/6776960

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView instead of listView because onTouchlistener will work more properly in recyclerview rather than listview.additionally listview have issue with adapting item position

Comment: Do you animate image from top to bottom??I am unable to understand this part of your question

Comment: no. I got images from my server in a recycler view and also i use on item click listener. it also working  i need to see previous image or next image using swipe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Answer (score 0):

add images in array.

```
int count=0;
int arr[count];
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivity.this) {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
count++;
img.setResource(arr[count]);
if(count>arr.length-1)
{
count=0;
}
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {

count--;
img.setResource(arr[count]);
if(count<0)
{
count=arr.length-1;
}
         Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }

    });
```

hope you got the answer